# Scala Named method arguments cannot resolve symbol

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, kubernetes

I am trying to use named arguments for the method because it has quite a lot of arguments. I am using java-client for Kubernetes API. However, I get `Cannot resolve symbol` compile error. I am writing the code in Intellij IDEA, could it be some plugins problem?

Here is the code:

```
  def createWatchOnPodsCalls() = {
    client.getHttpClient.setReadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    val watchEvents: Watch[V1Namespace]  = Watch.createWatch(client,
apiInstance.listClusterCustomObjectCall(group=null, version=null, plural=null, pretty="true", labelSelector = null, resourceVersion = null, watch = false, progressListener = null, progressRequestListener = null),
      new TypeToken[Watch.Response[V1Namespace]]{}.getType)
    watchEvents
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala 2.12 [supports named parameters for Java if they are available](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4735), but [by default Java is compiled without storing parameter names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html). So most Java libraries don't have them (because the benefit in Java itself is minimal), including even [the standard library](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-named-parameters-for-java-apis/812/6) (unless that has changed recently).

Comment: Well, I use Scala 2.12.7, but I get compile error anyway. So it means that for this library named arguments nay not be available?